# Multiprocessing/ Threading / asyncio for PyQt6 and python-can

Tags: python, pyqt, multiprocessing, can-bus, conceptual

EDIT: Relocated useless paragraphs.

**Program Background:**
I'm making a program to replace a radio controller for my car's head unit.
The goal is to create a GUI for a tablet to display the current screen and replace the current button controller for the (AC) Air Conditioning, and (AVU) Audio-Video-Navigation Unit.

**Program Structure:**

- PyQt6 -> Creates app (QApplication) ->
  Creates Window(QWidget) -> Creates Buttons (QButton) and Potentiometer(QSlider)
- Create Controller -> Connects to Virtual CAN Network -> Starts Periodic Send
- Configure Widgets -> Button Press -> Button Release -> Dial Change State -> Dial Release
- PyQt Main-Loop

**Flow Diagram**(hopefully useful....)
[Flow Diagram Showing Program Object Creation, and Flow of Message Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWmLE.png)

**The End Goal** #EDIT for clarity

- My GUI needs to be able to run continuously. When a button is pressed and held, I need to be able to check every 1/10 seconds whether or not it's still pressed.
- On button press, I need to send a message on the network, listen on the network for an acknowledge.
- On acknowledge receipt, if the last message wasn't a release-> wait 0.1 seconds, else return to main loop. If button is still pressed send another message, else send release message.

**Problems:**
If I create a can.Notifier object, the periodic messages on the network lock the interpreter, the debugger gets locked within repeated calls from the busy network. (There is a filter installed, but the specifc controller ID has a broadcast sent twice a second)

It seems like what I need is two, or multiple, main loops running.

1. A GUI - provides button status information or triggers function/method calls.
2. A network interface that reads/filters frames, and sends cyclic / instantaneous messages.
3. A top level controller that reads button states, and controls spacing between user messages.

My program works segregated.

1. I can connect to the network, send and receive messages, wait on acknowledge and send follow up.
2. I have a GUI with a grid array whose objects contain their specific can-frame-data lists.
3. I can send messages from the GUI to the network on press, release, state-change.

When I try to connect them all together, I get restricted by a cyclic process in one of those three apps.

1. The GUI can't update because the can.Notifier gets caught in processing new network messages.
2. When the GUI doesn't update, I cannot check QPushButton state or run QPushButton release events.
3. I can't make the interpreter wait for the 0.1 second delay without freezing the GUI, or missing the state change.

I appreciate anyone taking the time to help this cluster question.

##### UPDATE

Very constructive comments lead me to Qt's CAN and Threading packages/modules. I made the problem more difficult by attempting to create my own implementation of each without the background. Will post a write up  "how I solved" after creating an appropriate workflow.

Summarizing Bad Post Paragraphs:
*P1 - Apologizing for stack exchange inexperience.
**My Background:**
P2 - Stating beginner to intermediate programming experience.
**I'm missing a critical principal in programming and I can't identify the topic to go research.**
P3, P4 - Word salad about how the problem feels like a quick fix, and am looking for the buzz word to research.*

Comment: My first suggestion is to reduce the post to the actual question and focus in providing a very clear explanation: the whole background and your struggle in finding answers (first/last two paragraphs) are irrelevant to the problem and only contribute to make the question longer than it requires. Your usage of "button" is also misleading: "When a button is pressed and held" -> what button? The GUI or the *physical* ones? I've never used can-bus, but such I/O should always be moved to a separate thread with its own loop, *especially* if you need to wait for acknowledge/response.

Comment: This normally is done through a QThread subclass (or a QObject subclass moved to a QThread) that eventually notifies the main thread through signals, and the UI may eventually communicate back by using queues or signals (if using a standard QThread with its own loop). I'd suggest you to start from an *extremely* simple program that would just do that: send and receive messages to/from the network, ensuring that the main event loop is **never** blocked. With that, you'll better understand the underlying principles. Note that Qt provides a [CAN bus API](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcanbus-backends.html).

Comment: @musicamante 
Hey! I appreciate your responses. 

(To comment #1)
I actually wasn't aware of the QThread/CAN API options. I'm sure that's going be much more integrated than directly using the base packages. Your advice is pretty spot on too. Once I got to that point where everything worked separately, I'm sure I skipped the steps to start from the basics when using even the base level threading/multiprocessing packages.

Comment: (To cmnt #2)
There's a little bit of the new stack fear from posting something either blatantly obvious, or leaving out important details. Your direct examples are very helpful for moving forward.

In regard to post clarity (on buttons,) it is the same functionality for both physical and programmatic button use. Would something like,

"The program needs to check button state every 0.1s after the first press event, until it's released, then send the the release message." work better? 
(I'm updating first post and making solution post when ready)

Thanks again! I appreciate the guidance.

Comment: About the button check, no, it's not the same. I don't know how the interaction with the physical buttons happens, but with the UI there's absolutely no need to check every now and then if a button is pressed, since buttons have specific signals for both [`pressed`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#pressed) and [`released`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#released). A better approach would be a QTimer that sends the message every .1 seconds, start it on `pressed`, and stop it whenever the physical button has been released (acknowledge received) *or* the UI button has been released.

Comment: @musicamante That's an annoyingly simple approach lmao. You probably just saved 40 lines of code in a paragraph, thanks again for your time.